# Rails 3 ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError "unknown attribute: _destroy" for nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, destroy

Let's say I have a schema in which an apple crate contains zero or more apples.  While editing the apple crate in a form, I want to list the apples and provide a checkbox next to each apple, for deleting it when the form is submitted.

There is nothing going wrong that I can see.  In my model I say

```
class AppleCrate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apples
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :apples, :allow_destroy => true
  ...
end
```

I have the form working, so far as I can tell.  The checkboxes appear in the form html and when the form is processed by the controller each apple in the list has an attribute called "_destroy" which is set to either "1" or "0" depending on whether or not I checked the box before submitting.

According to the Rails API, when I set _destroy to 1 and save, the apple should be deleted.  But when I submit the form I get

> **ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in AppleCrateController#update**
>
> unknown attribute: _destroy
>
> ...
>
> "apple_crate"=>{"id"=>"10101", "apples"=>{"1"=>{"id"=>"1",
>   "variety"=>"granny smith", 
>   "apple_crate_id"=>"10101",
>   "_destroy"=>"1"}, 
>   "2"=>{"id"=>"2", 
>   "variety"=>"fuji",
>   "apple_crate_id"=>"10101",
>   "_destroy"=>"1"}, 
>   "3"=>{"id"=>"3",
>   "variety"=>"macintosh", 
>   "apple_crate_id"=>"10101", 
>   "_destroy"=>"0"},
>   ...

and so on.

I must be missing something obvious but after several days of futzing around I can't figure it out.  I can successfully do everything else -- update, edit, index, etc -- so long as I leave out the :_destroy attribute.  Any ideas?

(For what it's worth, I'm running rails 3.2.2 on Windows.)

Updated:

[This](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) is what I'm looking at in the documentation.  (See the subsection "One-to-many".)

Updated:

As requested in comments, here is the view:

```
<%= form_for @apple_crate do |f| %>
  <% @apples = @apple_crate.apples %>  
  <% @apples.each do |apple| %>
    <%= fields_for "apples[]", apple do |apple_fields| %>
      <%= apple_fields.text_field :variety %>
      <%= apple_fields.hidden_field :apple_crate_id %>
      <%= apple_fields.hidden_field :id %>
      <%= apple_fields.check_box :_destroy %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: according to [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/UnknownAttributeError.html) seems to be you need to add `attr_accessible :_destroy` to your AppleCrate model

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I'm not sure why that would be necessary:  _destroy isn't an actual model attribute.  I think it's supposed to be parsed during update_attributes.  In any event, I tried what you suggested and I got the same error message.

Comment: Seems to be I figured where might be an error. Please attach your form generation code, you should have `apples_attributes` instead of just `apples` in params hash

Comment: I have tried changing "apples[]" in the above view code to "apple_attributes[]", and made the corresponding change to the controller code, and get the same error.  I can call it anything -- "asdf[]" -- and I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate nested forms and forms with rails helpers, don't do it by your hands. So I think that's where your error at.

Try:

```
<%= form_for @apple_crate do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :apples do |apple_fields| %>
    <%= apple_fields.text_field :variety %>
    <%= apple_fields.hidden_field :apple_crate_id %>
    <%= apple_fields.hidden_field :id %>
    <%= apple_fields.check_box :_destroy %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

something like this, did not check if it's correct, but idea should be clear enough

Comment: That's the correct answer, and matches more closely the example in the API.  Thanks!  (The issue that I was having, just to be clear, is that I didn't understand that _destroy has no meaning outside the context of the parent AppleCrate.)